# Unity3D Custom editor focus change with EditorGUILayout.LabelField

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I've an issue working with custom editor, my editing focus is changed without any action from my part.
Basically, this is a screen of my custom editor in a neutral state (just added empty translation entity):

[image]

And this is a screen when my focus got change without reason. As you can see, my editor detected that 2 keys was the same and notify it by a message at the top of the box, the issue is that I was actually editing the second box's "key" field, and my focus changed on the first box (highlighted blue). If I don't display the warning message, I don't have any issue so I guess it comes from there..

[image]

This is my custom editor script :

```
    [CustomEditor(typeof(InternationalizationDatabaseSO))]
    public class InternationalizationDatabaseSOEditor : Editor
    {
        #region Constantes
        private const string ITEMS_PROPERTY_NAME = "_mItems";

        private const string ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME = "_mCategory";
        private const string ITEM_KEY_NAME = "_mKey";
        private const string ITEM_VALUES_NAME = "_mValues";

        private const string ITEM_VALUE_LANGUAGE = "_mLanguage";
        private const string ITEM_VALUE_VALUE = "_mValue";
        #endregion

        #region Attributs
        private InternationalizationDatabaseSO _mDatabase;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            _mDatabase = target as InternationalizationDatabaseSO;
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            SerializedProperty itemsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(ITEMS_PROPERTY_NAME);

            int arraySize = itemsProperty.arraySize;

            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(false);
            {
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                    if (OnInspectorGUIButton("+", 40, 25, Color.white, Color.green))
                    {
                        itemsProperty.arraySize++;
                        itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(itemsProperty.arraySize - 1).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME).stringValue = "";
                        itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(itemsProperty.arraySize - 1).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_KEY_NAME).stringValue = "";
                        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                        Init();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                EditorGUILayout.Space();

                for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    if(OnInspectorGUIItem(i) == false)
                    {
                        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                        Init();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        private bool OnInspectorGUIItem(int index)
        {
            SerializedProperty itemsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(ITEMS_PROPERTY_NAME);

            SerializedProperty itemCategory = itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME);
            SerializedProperty itemKey = itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_KEY_NAME);

            EditorGUI.indentLevel += 1;

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
            {
                EditorGUILayout.Space();
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                    {
                        if(KeyAlreadyExist(index, itemKey.stringValue))
                        {
                            OnInspectorGUIText("Key already exists", 12, Color.red, FontStyle.Bold, false);
                        }
                        OnInspectorGUIText("Key : " + itemKey.stringValue, 12, FontStyle.Normal, false);
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

                    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                    if(OnInspectorGUIButton("-", 40, 25, Color.white, Color.red))
                    {
                        itemCategory.stringValue = "";
                        itemKey.stringValue = "";
                        itemsProperty.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(index);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

                EditorGUILayout.Space();

                EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                {
                    GUIStyle style = EditorStyles.foldout;
                    style.fontSize = 15;
                    style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;


                    itemCategory.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(itemCategory.isExpanded, "General informations", style);
                    if(itemCategory.isExpanded)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.Space();
                        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemCategory, new GUIContent("Category"));
                        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemKey, new GUIContent("Key"));
                    }

                    if(OnInspectorGUIItemLanguage(index, itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index)) == false)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
            EditorGUI.indentLevel -= 1;
            return true;
        }

        private bool OnInspectorGUIItemLanguage(int index, SerializedProperty propertyItem)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
            {
                GUIStyle style = EditorStyles.foldout;
                style.fontSize = 15;
                style.normal.textColor = Color.black;
                style.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;

                SerializedProperty itemValues = propertyItem.FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_VALUES_NAME);
                itemValues.isExpanded = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(itemValues.isExpanded, "Languages informations", style);
                if(itemValues.isExpanded)
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                        {
                            int nbTranslation = itemValues.arraySize;
                            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Nb translation : " + nbTranslation);
                            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                            if (OnInspectorGUIButton("+", 20, 20, Color.white, Color.green))
                            {
                                itemValues.arraySize++;
                                itemValues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(itemValues.arraySize - 1).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_VALUE_LANGUAGE).intValue = 0;
                                itemValues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(itemValues.arraySize - 1).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_VALUE_VALUE).stringValue = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                        EditorGUILayout.Space();  
                        if (itemValues.arraySize > 0)
                        {
                            string translatedLanguages = "{";
                            foreach (InternationalizationDatabaseItemLanguage item in _mDatabase.Items[index].Values)
                            {
                                translatedLanguages += item.Language.ToString() + ", ";
                            }
                            if (translatedLanguages.Length > 2)
                            {
                                translatedLanguages = translatedLanguages.Remove(translatedLanguages.Length - 2);
                            }
                            translatedLanguages += "}";

                            //EditorStyles.label.stretchHeight = true;
                            EditorStyles.label.wordWrap = true;
                            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Translated : \n" + translatedLanguages);
                            EditorGUILayout.Space();

                            for (int i = 0; i < itemValues.arraySize; i++)
                            {
                                EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
                                {
                                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                                    InternationalizationDatabaseItemLanguage item = _mDatabase.Items[index].Values[i];
                                    SerializedProperty propLanguage = itemValues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_VALUE_LANGUAGE);
                                    SerializedProperty propValue = itemValues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative(ITEM_VALUE_VALUE);

                                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                                    {
                                        if (LanguageAlreadyExist(index, i, _mDatabase.Items[index].Values[i].Language))
                                        {
                                            OnInspectorGUIText("Warning language translation already exist", 12, Color.red, FontStyle.Bold, false);
                                        }

                                        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                                        if (OnInspectorGUIButton("-", 20, 20, Color.white, Color.red))
                                        {
                                            itemValues.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

                                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(propLanguage, new GUIContent("Language"));
                                    EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("Translation");
                                    propValue.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(propValue.stringValue, GUILayout.Height(80));

                                }
                                EditorGUILayout.Space();
                                EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
                                EditorGUILayout.Space();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
                }
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            return true;
        }

        private bool KeyAlreadyExist(int currentIndex, string key)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < _mDatabase.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                InternationalizationDatabaseItem item = _mDatabase.Items[i];
                if(currentIndex != i && item.Key == key && string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) == false)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool LanguageAlreadyExist(int indexInDatabase, int currentIndex, SystemLanguage language)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _mDatabase.Items[indexInDatabase].Values.Count; i++)
            {
                InternationalizationDatabaseItemLanguage item = _mDatabase.Items[indexInDatabase].Values[i];
                if (currentIndex != i && item.Language == language)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void OnInspectorGUIText(string text, FontStyle fontStyle, bool prefixLabel)
        {
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
            style.fontStyle = fontStyle;
            style.wordWrap = true;

            if (prefixLabel)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(text, GUIStyle.none, style);
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField(text, style);
            }
        }

        private void OnInspectorGUIText(string text, int fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle, bool prefixLabel)
        {
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
            style.fontSize = fontSize;
            style.fontStyle = fontStyle;
            style.wordWrap = true;

            if (prefixLabel)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(text, GUIStyle.none, style);
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField(text, style);
            }
        }

        private void OnInspectorGUIText(string text, int fontSize, Color textColor, FontStyle fontStyle, bool prefixLabel)
        {
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
            style.fontSize = fontSize;
            style.normal.textColor = textColor;
            style.fontStyle = fontStyle;
            style.wordWrap = true;

            if(prefixLabel)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(text, GUIStyle.none, style);
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField(text, style);
            }
        }

        private bool OnInspectorGUIButton(string label, int width, int height, Color textColor, Color backgroundColor)
        {
            Color saveColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
            GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.Width(width), GUILayout.Height(height) };
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
            style.normal.textColor = textColor;
            GUI.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

            bool pressed = GUILayout.Button(label, style, options);
            GUI.backgroundColor = saveColor;

            return pressed;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Have you any suggestion ? Thanks

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not sharing reference to the same property in both boxes ?

Comment: I don't think so, because if it was the case, when I'am editing one key, the other one should update at the same time. It is not the case here, the focus's problem occurs only the first time it detects that key is present more than 1 time.

Comment: You can try to use GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl in order to debug when your focus changes

Comment: Hi, after trying it, I can see that indeed my focus is changed, but still can't figure out why..

Comment: So if you comment out KeyAlreadyExist function call, there is no issue with changing focus?

Comment: Yeah exactly, but I solved it anyway so it's ok, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally figured it out, I mean, I'm not still totally certain why it happens, but found a workaround thanks to : https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-gui-inputfield-loses-focus-when-gui-updates.542147/

Basically, I'm just displaying always the LabelField, but if there is no error, I simply set the errorMessage to an empty string